# Changing the schedule of magento2 Crons

Tags: magento2, cron, best-practice, schedule

I have on setup on Magento and i have set cronjobs as per Magento guidelines as below.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/update/cron.php >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

When Magento projects get some more data like more Products, categories, orders. what is the best-practice to setup the cronjob schedule?

*** * * * *** This will run every minute on the server.
after our Magento project is getting bigger what is the **best practice** to set the cron job time.

we can set the cron setting like * * * * * all the time as this will consume all your memory and CPU both

Looking for suggestions.

Comment: [Amasty Cron Scheduler](https://amasty.com/cron-scheduler-for-magento-2.html) can help you to modify default Magento 2 schedules easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
* * * * *
```

This is the actual way of cron scheduling in magento. You don't have to change it.

There are 3 levels of cron scheduling in magento.

1. crontab - that you have used in question
2. the second is from `store->configuration->Advance->System->Cron`, here you can change the timing when magento will check scheduling in codebase
3. Last level is the scheduling in codebase. which you will find in `crontab.xml` in modules. This is the actual scheduling of cronjob.

The best way is to set magento cronjobs to `* * * * *` and from configuration use default values, and use your own scheduling in `crotab.xml`. So whenever you want to change scheduling you need to change in `crontab.xml`

Hope you find your answer :)

Comment: when our products, category will increase then what to do.. should we change the reindex cron schedule time?

Comment: No, use flat data structure. Also you can use **Update on Schedule** option in indexing instead of **Update on Save**. I have 25k+ products and I am using same settings. And website is working perfectly

Comment: ok, Thanks for replying.

Comment: sorry, one more question. if I set indexing **Update on Schedule** then on what time the indexing will happen..? means where is the setting where I can see/change indexing schedule time?

Comment: in `crontab.xml` of that module. Here is the actual scheduling

Comment: Did you find this answer useful?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100784/discussion-between-rizwan-khan-and-shoaib-munir).